# Can't make a while with sockets and tkinter python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tkinter

hope you are fine. I need help with my code, because I'm trying to build a "Battleship" with sockets and tkinter in python. Now I can make the board and position boats, but I have trouble when I try to make a "while" that send and receive the attacks from the enemy. Actually i don't send "attacks", i'm trying to  send the enemy matrix modified, make the changes in the board and return my matrix modified to the other player, and make this till the end of the game. The problem is that when i make my "while", tkinter just close the windows and the console waits for a command, but i cant "attack" without the tkinter windows, because every button in the board have the command "attack".
The game have client and a server.

pd: My english isn't the better, but i think is understandable what i'm trying to say.

```
def jugar(): #Function that send and recieve the matrix modified
    global Turno
    global ataquePresionado
    while verificarBarcosEnTablero():

        if Turno == "Jugador 2":
            ataqueEnemigo = recibirMensaje()
            recibirAtaque(ataqueEnemigo)
            Turno = "Jugador 1"

        elif Turno == "Jugador 1" and ataquePresionado == True:
            enviarMensaje(str(matrizEnemigo))
            Turno = "Jugador 2"
            ataquePresionado = False

def TableroJuego(): #Function that make the board
    global matrizBotones2
    global matrizBotones
    matrizBotones = []
    matrizCoordenadas = [0] * 20
    fila = 1
    columna = 1
    letra = ""
    k= 10
    l = 0

    ventanaTableroJuego = Tk()
    ventanaTableroJuego.resizable(0,0)
    ventanaTableroJuego.title("Battleship Servidor")
    framePadre = Frame(ventanaTableroJuego)
    framePadre.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky= W)
    framePadre.config(bg= "cyan4")

    for j in range(10):

        if j == 0:
              matrizCoordenadas[0] = Button(framePadre,text="+",width=6,height=3)
              matrizCoordenadas[0].grid(row= 0,column= 0)
              matrizCoordenadas[0].config(bg="cyan4", fg="white")

        if j == 0:
            letra = "A"
        elif j == 1:
            letra = "B"
        elif j == 2:
            letra = "C"
        elif j == 3 :
            letra = "D"
        elif j == 4:
            letra = "E"
        elif j == 5 :
            letra = "F"
        elif j == 6 :
            letra = "G"
        elif j ==  7:
            letra = "H"
        elif j == 8:
            letra = "I"
        elif j == 9:
            letra = "J"

        matrizCoordenadas[j+1] = (Button(framePadre,text=letra,width=6,height=3))
        matrizCoordenadas[j+1].grid(row= 0,column= j+1)
        matrizCoordenadas[j+1].config(bg="cyan3", fg="white")

        matrizCoordenadas[k] = (Button(framePadre,text=j+1,width=6,height=3,bg="white"))
        matrizCoordenadas[k].grid(row= j+1,column= 0)
        matrizCoordenadas[k].config(bg="cyan3", fg="white")
        k+=1

    for i in range(100):
        matrizBotones.append(Button(framePadre,text="",width=6,height=3))
        matrizBotones[i].grid(row= fila,column= columna)
        matrizBotones[i].config(bg="steel blue", command= lambda i=i: atacar(i))
        if columna%10==0 and columna != 1:
            fila+=1
            columna = 1
        else:
            columna+=1


    matrizCoordenadas2 = [0] * 20
    fila = 1
    columna = 1
    k= 10
    l = 0

    frameBarcos = Frame(framePadre)
    frameBarcos.grid(row = 1 , column = 11, rowspan= 5, sticky = W, padx=10)

    for i in range(100):
        matrizBotones2.append(Button(frameBarcos,text="",width=2,height=1))
        matrizBotones2[i].grid(row= fila,column= columna)
        matrizBotones2[i].config(bg="steel blue")
        if columna%10==0 and columna != 1:
            fila+=1
            columna = 1
        else:
            columna+=1

    for posicion in barco1tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="red")

    for posicion in barco2tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="yellow2")

    for posicion in barco3tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="magenta4")

    for posicion in barco4tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="darkorange")

    for posicion in barco5tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="green2")

    Label(framePadre, text="Barcos Propios", bg="cyan3",fg = "white", bd= 5, relief = RAISED, font= "Helvetica 11 bold italic").grid(row = 0, column=11, rowspan=1)

    Button(framePadre, text="Quien parte", bg="red", fg="white", command= lambda: botonQuienParte()).grid(row=7, column=11)

    print "Turno: ", Turno

    jugar() #HELP HERE PLEASE.

    ventanaTableroJuego.mainloop()
```

The code is longer than this, but i think that here is the problem.
Many thanks.

Comment: use `root.after(miliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while` to execute function periodically and let `mainloop()` does its job.

Comment: @furas i should use this in "jugar()"? i don't know how to use it, can u show me a little example please?

Comment: example [hot to update time in tkinter using after()](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

Comment: Don't mix GUI and Network Elements. All required a separated Thread because need handle all exception on your application. "When clicked a button send triger on socket" is awefull idea(Socket source is bussy,gui element not updated yet etc.). Use loader,container and gui class for checking every condutions and results. Otherwise you repeated more code on your script. Life is short, use python and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any user-interface toolkit, tkinter is *event driven*. It's only `while` loop is the `mainloop`.

So you have to play the game with events.

If you click on a button on the playing field to place a shot, you have to send the coordinates of that button to the other player's program in the event handler for the `<Button-1>` event.

The other player's program should listen for messages in a *timeout function* supplied to its main window's `after` method, update the display and send a response if you hit or missed.

You program should listen for messages from the other players program about incoming shells and hits and misses and update your board accordingly.

Comment: This is true but send signal on socket from `while True` ?

Comment: But how could i do that?

Comment: @dsgdfg I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Unanswered answer ! Wait answer for update element , can you explain where is solution method ? I don't care you don't understand me , question asker understand you ? Nah ! @RolandSmith